# jQuery Accordion Shrinks Google Charts if not in First Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a few different [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) that i want to put inside the sections of a jQuery accordion.  The problem is that all the charts that are not inside the first part of the accordion are smaller for some reason.  Something about the accordion is shrinking these charts.  I do not want them to shrink.  Does anyone know what I can do to keep them from shrinking?

See this example which illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dN3LL/

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So from the answer provided by brandwaffle, I considered that the graphics should render before the divs are collapsed into accordion form, so I simply put the `$('#accordion').accordion();` line right after the graphs are finished rendering, and it works!  See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dN3LL/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen to me with various different pieces of content in the past. I think the problem happens because the content is rendered in a collapsed container, so it defaults to the smallest possible size (I've seen this with content in flexible-width divs inside of the accordion as well). The best solution I can offer for an across-the-board resolution is to hook whatever google chart generation (or other content display) to the accordionchange event that jQueryUI's Accordion offers: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

If you use the accordionchange event, the Google Chart will render itself after the accordion has switched to the correct section, which should eliminate any problems you're having as a result of the chart trying to render into a squished (i.e. unopened) container. There may be a better CSS fix for this, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have come up with a little workaround much easier then re-rendering on each change event.

Answer (score 0):

one workaround is, load chart first and then run accordion code once chart load complete or  run accordion code after 1-2 sec (setTimeout)